# Markup inside Fitnesse test table

Tags: fitnesse

I want to use markup like '''text''' (format text as bold) to format text inside a Fitnesse test table to show in a complex setup, which specific values are tested.

Example: If I have a test table like this

```
|query|load and check age of person|
|name |age                         |
|Peter|'''40'''                    |
```

I get "40" as bold text, which is what I want. But when I run the test I get an error, saying for the result

```
[40] expected [40]
```

inside that table. The same happens if I use css classes with e.g.

```
!style_red[40]
```

Is there a way to do format text, without breaking the tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I'm aware of is to do this in code (removing the HTML tags before doing the actual compare operation).

Comment: That's what I expected... And this is definitely too much effort!